# Error in Xcode, can't see attribute for text field

Tags: ios7, xcode5

This is the first time I program with Xcode,

At storyboard, my text field's attribute doesn't look like in Apple tutorial, I post it here:

> Pictures

In my Xcode:

[image]

In tutorial:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really quiet simple my friend. the issue is that your textfield attribute is not expanded. in your story board, click on the textfield and then when it shows the attribute window on the right panel, click your mouse on the textfield title on top left of that window to expand it and see all the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have Xcode 4 installed and your tutorial image is form Xcode 5.   You should see an update listed in the App Store.  See https://developer.apple.com/xcode/.

Comment: I don't think so, my version is 5.0.2, please check this picture:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/S0t5a.png